# Error while executing 'php artisan optimize'

Tags: php, laravel-5.7, laravel-artisan

Recently i try to install a new package on my Laravel platform and I get the below error:

```
Configuration cache cleared!

In ConfigCacheCommand.php line 71:

  Your configuration files are not serializable.


In ForwardsCalls.php line 50:

  Call to undefined method App\Post::__set_state()
```

I already have made a little search on google about it and I can't find any solution that really work.

I try to remove the vendor folder and do composer update to reinstall all packages and I also try to remove the files in the bootstrap\cache folder.

My composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "3.2.*",
        "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
        "google/recaptcha": "~1.1",
        "intervention/image": "^2.3",
        "laravel/socialite": "^3.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^5.3.0",
        "stripe/stripe-php": "^4.5",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^1.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.3|~6.0",
        "spatie/laravel-translatable": "3.1.3",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.9",
        "riverskies/laravel-mobile-detect" : "1.2.2"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
    "files": [
            "app/helpers.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "secure-http":false
    }
}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure in laravel 5.7 there is no more the command php artisan optimize

Comment: do you have PHP resources in your config?

Comment: No I have no resources in my php config